# Permute an array [A1, B1, A2, B2, A3, B3,......An, Bn] into [A1, A2, A3,......,An,B1, B2, B3,....,Bn] without using any extra space and in linear time

Tags: algorithm, sorting, permutation, shuffle, in-place

How to permute an array [A1, B1, A2, B2, A3, B3,......An, Bn] into [A1, A2, A3,......,An,B1, B2, B3,....,Bn] without using any extra space and in linear time? Here Ai and Bj all are segments of words, where all Ai & Bj have same count of words among them but different from each other. That is, A1, A2, ... have say, 'k' words in them but B1, B2,... have 'p' words in them.

I have already found the reverse of the above algorithm online at multiple places but couldn't find the solution for this exact problem.

Comment: This sounds interesting, but the "segments of words" stuff is really unclear. Would be good to provide an actual example. And a link to the reverse algorithm would be good.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/332/in-place-algorithm-for-interleaving-an-array (link to the reverse algorithm)

Comment: Also, I have A1, B1, A2, B2, .... segments where Ai(s) contains "al" words and Bi(s) contains "a(w-l)" words. There are total "n" words spread across "n/aw" (Ai,Bi) pairs i.e. (2*n)/(a*w) segments in total, half of which are in Ai s and other half in Bi s. That "i" in subscript which I'm referring to values from 1 to (n/(a*w)).